# get indexes with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How do I find a position(index) of all entries of search_value?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
search_value=8
lst=[5, 8, 2, 7, 8, 8, 2, 4]
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
df["is_search_value"]=np.where(df[0]==search_value, True, False)
print(df.head(20))
```

Output:

```
   0  is_search_value
0  5            False
1  8             True
2  2            False
3  7            False
4  8             True
5  8             True
6  2            False
7  4            False
```

Desirable output:

```
1 4 5
```

If search_value is 10 than desirable output:

```
None
```

Comment: If you don't pass True and False to np.where, it returns indices (`np.where(df[0]==search_value)`). You'll get `(array([1, 4, 5]),)`.

Comment: @ayhan if I don't pass True and False I'm getting error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"

Comment: Are you sure? `np.where(df[0]==search_value)` returns `(array([1, 4, 5]),)` in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use enumerate in a conditional list comprehension to get the index locations.

```
my_list = [5, 8, 2, 7, 8, 8, 2, 4]
search_value = 8
>>> [i for i, n in enumerate(my_list) if n == search_value]
[1, 4, 5]
```

If the search value is not in the list, then an empty list will be returned (not exactly None, but still a falsey).

Using pandas, you can use boolean indexing to get the matches, then extract the index to a list:

```
df[df[0] == search_value].index.tolist()
```

Using an empty list will satisfy the condition for None (they both evaluate to False).  If you *really* need None, then use the suggestion of @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.

Comment: List comprehension? Where are pandas in that?

Comment: @user2978216 You don't have to shoot a gun when a pistol is more than enough.

Comment: Heheh, these comments. Also, for OP's requirement of returning None, the condition would be `df.index[df[0] == search_value].tolist() or None`.

Comment: @user2978216 the panda's at the bottom next to his username

Answer (score 1):

If you pass to `np.where()` only condition - it'll return indices of matched elements:

```
In [29]: np.where(df[0]==search_value)
Out[29]: (array([1, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
```

For custom Pandas indices:

```
In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame(lst, index=np.arange(8)[::-1])

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
   0
7  5
6  8
5  2
4  7
3  8
2  8
1  2
0  4

In [41]: df.index[np.where(df[0]==search_value)]
Out[41]: Int64Index([6, 3, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

with pandas

```
>>> (pd.Series([5, 8, 2, 7, 8, 8, 2, 4]) == 8).nonzero()
(array([1, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: @ayhan Yes, my mistake.